# Not able to drop columns in a matrix using Drop

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

```
   R= {{(1/2 Cos[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) Sin[b (L - z1)] + 
       Cosh[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Sin[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) + 
       Cos[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sin[b z1] - 
          1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) + (1/2 Cos[b z1] + 
          1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) Sinh[b (L - z1)], 
      Cos[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Cos[b z1] - 
          1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) + (-(1/2) Cos[b z1] - 
          1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) Cosh[b (L - z1)] + 
       Sin[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Sin[b z1] + 
          1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) + (-(1/2) Sin[b z1] - 
          1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) Sinh[
         b (L - z1)], (1/2 Cosh[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[t] Cosh[b z1]) Sin[
         b (L - z1)] + (1/2 Cosh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t/2]^2 Cosh[b z1] + 
          1/2 Cosh[b z1] Sin[t/2]^2) Sinh[b (L - z1)] + 
       Cos[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Sinh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sinh[b z1]) + 
       Cosh[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sinh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sinh[b z1]), 
      Cos[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Cosh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Cosh[b z1]) + 
       Cosh[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Cosh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Cosh[b z1]) + 
       Sin[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sinh[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[t] Sinh[b z1]) + 
       Sinh[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sinh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t/2]^2 Sinh[b z1] + 
          1/2 Sin[t/2]^2 Sinh[b z1]), 
      1/2 Cos[b (L - z1)] Cos[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] + 
       1/2 Cos[a b^2 z1] Cosh[b (L - z1)] Sin[t] - (
       a A L^2 Sin[b (L - z1)] Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t])/(2 b Iyy) + (
       a A L^2 Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] Sinh[b (L - z1)])/(2 b Iyy), (
       a A L^2 Cos[a b^2 z1] Sin[b (L - z1)] Sin[t])/(2 b Iyy) + 
       1/2 Cos[b (L - z1)] Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] + 
       1/2 Cosh[b (L - z1)] Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] - (
       a A L^2 Cos[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] Sinh[b (L - z1)])/(
       2 b Iyy)}, {-b^2 (1/2 Cos[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) Sin[
         b (L - z1)] + 
       b^2 Cosh[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Sin[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) - 
       b^2 Cos[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sin[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) + 
       b^2 (1/2 Cos[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) Sinh[
         b (L - z1)], -b^2 Cos[
         b (L - z1)] (1/2 Cos[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) + 
       b^2 (-(1/2) Cos[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) Cosh[b (L - z1)] - 
       b^2 Sin[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Sin[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) + 
       b^2 (-(1/2) Sin[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) Sinh[
         b (L - z1)], -b^2 (1/2 Cosh[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[t] Cosh[b z1]) Sin[
         b (L - z1)] + 
       b^2 (1/2 Cosh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t/2]^2 Cosh[b z1] + 
          1/2 Cosh[b z1] Sin[t/2]^2) Sinh[b (L - z1)] - 
       b^2 Cos[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Sinh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sinh[b z1]) + 
       b^2 Cosh[
         b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sinh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sinh[b z1]), -b^2 Cos[
         b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Cosh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Cosh[b z1]) + 
       b^2 Cosh[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Cosh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Cosh[b z1]) - 
       b^2 Sin[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sinh[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[t] Sinh[b z1]) + 
       b^2 Sinh[
         b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sinh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t/2]^2 Sinh[b z1] + 
          1/2 Sin[t/2]^2 Sinh[b z1]), -(1/2) b^2 Cos[b (L - z1)] Cos[
         a b^2 z1] Sin[t] + 
       1/2 b^2 Cos[a b^2 z1] Cosh[b (L - z1)] Sin[t] + (
       a A b L^2 Sin[b (L - z1)] Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t])/(2 Iyy) + (
       a A b L^2 Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] Sinh[b (L - z1)])/(
       2 Iyy), -((a A b L^2 Cos[a b^2 z1] Sin[b (L - z1)] Sin[t])/(
        2 Iyy)) - 1/2 b^2 Cos[b (L - z1)] Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] + 
       1/2 b^2 Cosh[b (L - z1)] Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] - (
       a A b L^2 Cos[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] Sinh[b (L - z1)])/(
       2 Iyy)}, {-b^2 (1/2 Cos[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) Sin[
         b (L - z1)] + 
       b^2 Cosh[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Sin[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) - 
       b^2 Cos[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sin[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) + 
       b^2 (1/2 Cos[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) Sinh[
         b (L - z1)], -b^2 Cos[
         b (L - z1)] (1/2 Cos[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) + 
       b^2 (-(1/2) Cos[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[b z1] Cos[t]) Cosh[b (L - z1)] - 
       b^2 Sin[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Sin[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) + 
       b^2 (-(1/2) Sin[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sin[b z1]) Sinh[
         b (L - z1)], -b^2 (1/2 Cosh[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[t] Cosh[b z1]) Sin[
         b (L - z1)] + 
       b^2 (1/2 Cosh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t/2]^2 Cosh[b z1] + 
          1/2 Cosh[b z1] Sin[t/2]^2) Sinh[b (L - z1)] - 
       b^2 Cos[b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Sinh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sinh[b z1]) + 
       b^2 Cosh[
         b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sinh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Sinh[b z1]), -b^2 Cos[
         b (L - z1)] (-(1/2) Cosh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Cosh[b z1]) + 
       b^2 Cosh[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Cosh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t] Cosh[b z1]) - 
       b^2 Sin[b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sinh[b z1] + 1/2 Cos[t] Sinh[b z1]) + 
       b^2 Sinh[
         b (L - z1)] (1/2 Sinh[b z1] - 1/2 Cos[t/2]^2 Sinh[b z1] + 
          1/2 Sin[t/2]^2 Sinh[b z1]), -(1/2) b^2 Cos[b (L - z1)] Cos[
         a b^2 z1] Sin[t] + 
       1/2 b^2 Cos[a b^2 z1] Cosh[b (L - z1)] Sin[t] + (
       a A b L^2 Sin[b (L - z1)] Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t])/(2 Iyy) + (
       a A b L^2 Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] Sinh[b (L - z1)])/(
       2 Iyy), -((a A b L^2 Cos[a b^2 z1] Sin[b (L - z1)] Sin[t])/(
        2 Iyy)) - 1/2 b^2 Cos[b (L - z1)] Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] + 
       1/2 b^2 Cosh[b (L - z1)] Sin[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] - (
       a A b L^2 Cos[a b^2 z1] Sin[t] Sinh[b (L - z1)])/(2 Iyy)}};
    Dimensions[R]
    MatrixForm[R];
    R = Drop[R, {}, {2, 4, 5}];
    MatrixForm[R]
    Dimensions[R]
```

I have a matrix `R` with dimension `3*6`, I want to delete columns `(2, 4, 5)`. I tried `Drop`, but it seems like it is not working. The matrix is reducing to dimension `3*5`. `Drop` works for a matrix containing numbers, but not working well if the matrix consists of symbolic variables.

How do I overcome this?

Also, I tried `DeleteCases` and `Delete`, but I still did not get what I wanted.

Mathematica is not giving an error messsage, but the answer it is giving is wrong.

Comment: Why don't you give simply `R = Array[r, {3,6}]` as a _minima_ example?

Comment: The syntax `Drop[R, {}, {2, 4, 5}]` tells Mathematica to drop colums 2 to 4 in steps of 5. Since 2+5>4, only column 2 is dropped.

Comment: I know drop function is working for a matrix with the number. But for a matrix with symbols, it is not working. That is why I put everything in the question.

Comment: No, there is no difference in the behavior for matrices with or without symbols.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I did not understand the syntax properly.

Comment: No problem. Imho, the documentation for `Drop` is a bit hard to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax `Drop[R, {}, {2, 4, 5}]` tells Mathematica to drop colums 2 to 4 in steps of 5. Since 2+5>4, only column 2 is dropped.

What you want to do can be done, for example, with

```
R[[All, Complement[Range[Dimensions[R][[2]]], {2, 4, 5}]]]
```

or

```
R[[All, {1,3,6}]]
```

Answer (score 8):

Here are some formulations that allow you to work in terms of the column indexes of the columns you want to delete, rather than their complement.

Let `r` be defined by

```
r = Array[a, {3, 6}]
```

> ```
> {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[1, 4], a[1, 5], a[1, 6]}, 
>  {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 3], a[2, 4], a[2, 5], a[2, 6]}, 
>  {a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3], a[3, 4], a[3, 5], a[3, 6]}}
> ```

Then evaluating any of follow expressions

```
ReplacePart[r, {_, 2 | 4 | 5} -> Nothing]
Delete[{{2}, {4}, {5}}] /@ r
MapAt[Nothing, {{2}, {4}, {5}}] /@ r
```

will give

> ```
> {{a[1, 1], a[1, 3], a[1, 6]}, 
>  {a[2, 1], a[2, 3], a[2, 6]}, 
>  {a[3, 1], a[3, 3], a[3, 6]}}
> ```

Comment: Nice! (+1)  As a side remark: It might not be relevant to the OP for their matrix is rather small, but each of this method unpacks arrays.